# Wrapping Several AWS Services Behind the same Domain Name

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

G'day,

I am trying to have a setup where I have three services - S3, Cognito and GraphQL, at the backend.

What I will like to achieve is to be able to host them behind the same domain and CDN. Same domain is the consideration to avoid having to deal with unnecessary browser sandbox issues (e.g. same origin policy).

In addition, I also have several environments: prod, sandbox and dev.

Hence I will need to have have the follow-up setups too:

- prod.domainname.com
- sandbox.domainname.com
- dev.domainname.com

I have wrapped CloudFront across the 3 services in each environment. It works beautifully.

When I tried to go production, I need "domainname.com" and "www.domainname.com" to be pointing to "prod.domainname.com".

This is where I faced some issues. Because the SSL certificates are issued to prod.domainname.com, I am getting some issues when mapping. The browser is giving issues as the SSL does not map the new domain. (Eg. SSL is issued to prod.domainname.com, but the URL is [www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com)).

I tried a little hack by placing NGIX across the 3 services, and then wrapping the CloudFront over it instead. I was wondering if there's a simpler way to achieve this without the NGIX?

Comment: Why you are not creating `*` certicate so the browser will not complain. `*.domainname.com` and AWS provide it free

Comment: `*.domainname.com`   will usually not cover `domainname.com`. Thus you should  register a single cert for both these domains if you want to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to use [Subject Alternative Names](https://www.entrustdatacard.com/blog/2019/march/what-is-a-san-and-how-is-it-used) in the certificate. This allows a certificate to be valid for multiple domains.

Steps 3 and 4 on [this AWS documentation page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/gs-acm-request-public.html) covers that using AWS Certificate Manager.